# Did Darth Vader post-ROTS ever engage in sexual activity in canon?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

It's a known fact that powerful people - especially in autocratic regimes - enjoy considerable access to sexual favors (witness Beria, or members of Saddam's government for well known excesses).

In Star Wars, we know that the Emperor himself had consorts (e.g. [Ismaren](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Roganda_Ismaren), [Isard](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ysanne_Isard)).

I think that is reasonable to assume that the Emperor's right hand (post-*RotS* Darth Vader) took advantage of the (probably a lot of) ways of "entertainment" at his disposal.

**But I want to know if this indeed happened in canon (Legends or Disney).**

To clarify, *(as @DampeSBN pointed out in comments)*, sex is not limited to genital contact - I'm interested in any activity/relationship that may be deemed sexual.

P.S. As far as Vader's plausible motivation, I was specifically thinking about a hypothetical situation in which Darth Vader became interested in a "escort" (or your favorite slang word) with a physical resemblance to Padme.

Comment: So when Vader said "I am your father" he was lying?

Comment: To clarify -- it looks like you are asking AFTER he became 'Darth Vader'

Comment: And just to be especially clear - you are aware that Anakin had become Darth Vader *before* he got put in the suit?  I.e. it wasn't the suit that made him Vader.

Comment: __Important Information:__ The definition of _sex_ does not require _genital contact_. If Vader engaged in any kind of act that produced _sexual pleasure_ in himself or others (or _sexual displeasure_, as the case might be) that is _sex_.

Comment: This question is crazy. Are you going to ask if Robocop did the dirty next?

Comment: @DampeS8N - is that you, Mr Ex-President?

Comment: He didn't become a different person just because he got disfigured and changed his name you know. So yes, Anakin = Vader.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I remember hearing an old saying - if you want to know a persons hangups, listen to their jokes.  Wonder if the same is true of certain questions on this site.

Comment: One serious problem is that Vader's frank and beans and nearly everything else were burned beyond recognition in episode 3.  Vader went up like he was soaked in kerosene.  Second degree burns at a minimum, scarring, nerve damage, everywhere.  Skin is pretty darned important in sexual relations and Vader didn't have much left.  He did seem to have a working set of lips and a tongue, so make of that what you may.

Comment: Given the downvotes to date, going to be real surprised if this get's re-opened.  I left my VTC in place.  Even with the more specific edit, still a matter of opinion.  Have to wonder why anyone would be interested in knowing this.  Maybe is one was a sociologist but even so, believe this is of extremely limited interested to the folks in the community.

Comment: I re-edited and am reversing my VTC

Comment: @DVK Because...?

Comment: @Keen - because upon re-thinking, it's not in any way opinion based. I can't imagine what I was thinking when I cast that vote (I suspect mine wasn't "O.B" reason). I'm unsure if it has an answer, but it's definitely **answerable**. Also, a similar question about Luke Skywalker was NOT closed and deemed on topic

Comment: @DVK Thanks for your changing of mind, and your expanded editing.

Comment: Let me just say what we're all thinking: "Doctor, I experienced a terrible burning sensation in my genitals."

Comment: Geez, what's next? How else did Jar Jar use his talented tongue?

Answer (score 21):

As kind of the *Null Hypothesis*. I'm saying that **No, he did not**. I have not found any canonical information that suggests that Vader ever engaged in any sexual conduct once in his suit. No lovers. No rapes. No mis/conduct of any kind.

Outside of canon. Sometimes I really hate the internet.

-- Update --

Since Disney de-canonified most of the EU, this answer can now be considered definitive.

Comment: I wonder if Rule 34 applies to Stack Exchange answers *as a topic*

Comment: @DVK:
I know I voted to close an answer to a different question that invoked Rule 34 for an answer, so there's precedent. :)

Comment: "Legends" canon is still a kind of canon. It's not to be confused with "non-canon" (i.e. fan fiction or robot chicken or Lego star wars )

Comment: The *Null Hypothesis* would be a good name for a Star Destroyer.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 A Null Hypothesis is an assertion about a p-value. This question is asking about Vader's p-p-value.

Answer (score 2):

After he got his suit, he was burnt beyond recognition. He had no organic arms left and only one organic leg;  the rest are all prosthetics.  He also had third degree burns all over his body which basically frays the nerve endings ensuring he can't physically feel anything.  That includes his genitalia, and since sexual pleasure is a physical sensation he wouldn't get much out of it.  Add that to the fact that his life has been stripped of all happiness and replaced with a burning hatred for all things Jedi, and being trained as a Sith he really wouldn't have much in the way of motivation.  So, all in all, any sexual activity that he would have participated in would have been utterly pointless due to the lack of pleasure he would feel and the fact that he wouldn't care if his partner felt any pleasure.

Comment: That was the most ridiculously long sentence I've ever seen (yes, it was all ONE sentence).  Good argument, but some punctuation and line breaks would be nice, in the future.

Comment: Sorry I get carried away and forget about the little things. (You can see this by looking at any of my other posts). Plus I haven't been on the site for awhile.

Comment: One organic leg?  As I recall from ROTS, the only limb he had after the "high ground" failure was his prosthetic arm; both legs were gone in mid-thigh, as well as the previously whole arm above the elbow.

Comment: “since sexual pleasure is a physical sensation he wouldn't get much out of it” — sure, but if he’s all mechanical prosthetics now, his partners could have a _great_ time. Also sex can be about stuff other than physical sensations.